# Specific part of an impulse response matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, fft, windowing

I measure the impulse response of a microphone. At beginning of plot i have some delay and then highest value comes at 40 ms and decreases till 45 ms. 
When I take fourier transform, I only want to use the part between 35-45 ms. when I use different microphones, delay decreases or increases so the peak value is shifting. So, the time range I want also changes. How I can get that range, which contains highest value, automaticaly in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a vector `y` of measurements and want an interval of length `2r+1` measurements you could do:

```
center = find(y==max(y));         % find the peak value

y_edited = y(center-r:center+r);  % look at r samples before and after this peak
```

Then perform the fourier transform on `y_edited`. Note that having noise on your signal might affect your performance.

Comment: yes my signal have some noise and my fft result fluctuates so much. I know that my microphone has a flat frequency response but I dont see that in my fft and impresp.

Comment: @puCCa if you want more help, I suggest adding some more information to your original question, such as a graph of your impulse response and its Fourier transform, and how you think it SHOULD look. As far as I can tell the code I provided should answer your original question, but given your comment you might have to look into filtering rather than windowing. I can't tell for sure though without more information.